# Unwanted padding on button img

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a button in my HTML And on CSS I created a fading hover effect

```css
.hvr-fade3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: rgba(107,176,254,0.90);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color;
  transition-property: color, background-color;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.hvr-fade3:hover, .hvr-fade3:focus, .hvr-fade3:active {
  background-color: rgba(108,247,97,0.82);
  color: white;
}
.hvr-fade3 img {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  opacity:0.8;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="cloneSelect()" class="hvr-fade3"><img src="images/plusbt.svg"></button>
```

However the image looks like it has some unwanted padding and looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove the extra white space and have the blue circle span the whole circle?

The original image was created in illustrator and looks like this:
[image]

**UPDATE** After setting the padding to padding: 0px; the img looks like this

[image]

Thanks,
oliver

Comment: Can you also show us what the original image looks like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen just did so!

Comment: Try adding `padding:0px;` in hvr-fade3 class css

Comment: Does setting `padding: 0` on the `.hvr-fade3` style fix it?

Comment: use overflow:hidden then border-radius: 50% in your .hvr-fade3

Comment: I think you should make the white background area transparent *in the image* itself, and then not use border-radius in the CSS.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes the padding 0 make it span alot more, I still got a bit of padding but I guess it might be the browser! so simple! thanks folks

Comment: maybe you cut your image with white background

Comment: @user3818576 I dont think its the background, when I hover on the img src in dreamweaver it shows the background transparent and no white borders just like the one in illustrator

Comment: i think you need to update your browser. :)

Comment: @user3818576 all are updated, on chrome looks better than firefox, the images above are from firefox ;)